# Grouping Column Headers in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013, ms-access-2016

Ok so I'm aware of grouping rows in Ms Access Reports or Crosstab Queries but can you group column headers?

I have a query with the following fields

DaysWork___Source___Opening___CashIN___CashOUT

1/10/18____Cashier1___1500______800______200

1/10/18____Cashier2___130_______100______900

2/10/18_____Cashier1__1500______500______250

2/10/18_____Cashier2__1300______150_______25

Can I get the query to be displayed like this in a report or another query

DaysWork___________Cashier1_______________________Cashier2
___________Opening___CashIN___CashOUT___Opening___CashIN___CashOUT
1/10/18______1500_______800______200_______1300_____100______900
2/10/18______1500_______500______250_______1300_____150_______25

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, SQL has no required feature.
If cashier names are fixed and known number of cashiers, you can use a query like this:

```
SELECT DaysWork
    ,Max(IIf(Source <> 'Cashier1', NULL, Opening)) AS Opening_1
    ,Max(IIf(Source <> 'Cashier1', NULL, CashIN)) AS CashIN_1
    ,Max(IIf(Source <> 'Cashier1', NULL, CashOUT)) AS CashOUT_1
    ,Max(IIf(Source <> 'Cashier2', NULL, Opening)) AS Opening_2
    ,Max(IIf(Source <> 'Cashier2', NULL, CashIN)) AS CashIN_2
    ,Max(IIf(Source <> 'Cashier2', NULL, CashOUT)) AS CashOUT_2
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY DaysWork
```

Also you can create a query and use it instead of `MyTable`, where each cashier has a corresponding number and use those numbers instaed of `Source` column in report query. In this case you don't need to know cashier names, but number of different cashiers should be limited

```
SELECT DaysWork
    ,Max(IIf(CashierNo <> 1, NULL, Opening)) AS Opening_1
    ,Max(IIf(CashierNo <> 1, NULL, CashIN)) AS CashIN_1
    ,Max(IIf(CashierNo <> 1, NULL, CashOUT)) AS CashOUT_1
    ,Max(IIf(CashierNo <> 2, NULL, Opening)) AS Opening_2
    ,Max(IIf(CashierNo <> 2, NULL, CashIN)) AS CashIN_2
    ,Max(IIf(CashierNo <> 2, NULL, CashOUT)) AS CashOUT_2
FROM qry_OnMyTable
GROUP BY DaysWork
```

Comment: Not the results I'm looking for. I'm looking to get 1 Column Header displaying the different Cashiers and a next Column Header with Opening,CashIN and CashOUT for each Cashier.

Comment: After further research and hours of Googling I've found out what I'm trying to do is not possible in MS Access 2016. I am looking for a pivot table design and Access 2016 does not support it. You need to link the data to Excel to get the design I wanted. So, if I still need to revert to excel to get reports....I guess that I have to abandon my Access project and just build a dashboard for the Excel spreadsheet.